# Comparing a strings value to the value of a boolean

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to compare the values of the boolean (all of which are `0`) to the values of this string array `data[] = "1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1"`. This is my code:

```
recipeIngrediants = new boolean[numberOfCuisines][numberOfIngrediants];
        int i = 0;
        while(file.hasNextLine()){
            String temp = file.nextLine();
            String[] data = temp.split(",");
        for(int j=0; j < recipeIngrediants.length; j++){
            String c = data[j];
            if(c == "1"){
                recipeIngrediants[i][j] = true;
            }
            else{
                recipeIngrediants[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
        i++;
     }
```

I get an error saying that it is a type mismatch. 
EDIT: Fixed the type mismatch error but it still gives me a value of false for all values in the boolean

**Question:**

How else can I compare these values to get the 2D array of `recipeIngrediants` to equal `true` at whatever position in `data` has a `1`?

Comment: You are assigning `"1"` to `c` instead of comparing the values... Make it `c == "1"` in the `if` condition. No, better use `c.equals("c")`

Comment: First of all make sure you are not incorrectly using = instead of ==, secondly strings are tested for equality using .equals() and not ==

Comment: `c = "1"` is assigning `"1"` to the variable `c`.  The return value of an assignment is the value being assigned; so `if (c = "1" != null)` is effective `c = "1"; if (true)`.  `String` comparisons (and all other `Object`s) should be done with `Object.equals` in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want to assign to the array items `true` for every string `c` that evaluates to `"1"` and `false` otherwise:

```
recipeIngrediants = new boolean[numberOfCuisines][numberOfIngrediants];
int i = 0;
while(file.hasNextLine()){
    String temp = file.nextLine();
    String[] data = temp.split(",");
    for(int j=0; j < recipeIngrediants.length; j++){
        String c = data[j];
        recipeIngrediants[i][j] = (c != null) && (c.equals("1"));
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so using the null check and the .equals operator instead of "==" worked. Although because its a jagged array at other points i needed to add recipeIngrediants[i].length to the for loop. Thank you!

Comment: @KyleCroumer I don't know if you really need the null check. I saw it in your code. Of course you need to check not to bypass the length of the array.